# php Cookie not working, won't get set

Tags: php, cookies

When I submit the form to the action processing script, I am supposed to set the cookie. But the cookie doesn't get set.

```
<input type="email" name="fes-email" class="fes-input" value="<?php echo $_COOKIE['hotspot-user-email']; ?>" placeholder="Еmail">
```

This is found on the processing script page.

```
setcookie('hotspot-user-email', $_POST['fes-email'], time() + (86400 * 30), 'domain.tld');
```

What I am attempting is to save the email address in a cookie, so that the next time the user returns the address will be echoed in the input field.

Is there a problem with my code?

```
if(!empty($_POST['fes-email'])) {

            if (filter_var($_POST['fes-email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {

                setcookie('hotspot-user-email', $_POST['fes-email'], time() + (86400 * 30), '/'); // 86400 = 1 day

            }else { echo("EMAIL IS NOT VALID"); }

        }else { echo("EMPTY FIELD"); }
```

Comment: You are setting cookie name as 'hotspot-user-email', but retrieving it as 'uniroyal.mk-hotspot-user-email'. Is there any other code snippet which you have not shared? Also, check the return value of "setcookie"

Comment: @ghopst I just modified the name when I posted it here. Problem is the cookie isn't being set. When I go into chrome cookies and search for it, it's not there.

Comment: @ghopst As for another snipped. Not really. It's contained in an if statement. That validates the email address. If the email address is correctly written, it should set the cookie. But it doesn't.

Comment: Please post your complete code

Comment: @CodingHorror there posted...

Comment: Also make sure your set_cookie() function is before the <html>tag

Comment: Complete code would be good. As for some guidelines for setting cookie - "setcookie" must be called before any print statement in the code. People will be able to help you if they exactly what you are doing.

Comment: @CodingHorror There is no html whatsoever in the processing page. It's all php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following is the simplest snippet that does the magic

```
<?php
  if (isset($_COOKIE['testCookie'])) {
      echo "<br/> Cookie is set: " . $_COOKIE['testCookie'] ." <br/>";
  } else {
      if (setcookie('testCookie','myemail@mydomain.com', time() + 86400)) {
          echo "<br/> cookie is set <br/>";
      }
  }
?>
```

Comment: Did you refresh the page? I tested it myself and its working perfectly fine. On refresh, you get "Cookie is set: myemail@mydomain.com"

Answer (score 1):

you set cookie just for "domain.tld"

please test this code for all page of this address:

```
setcookie('hotspot-user-email', $_POST['fes-email'], time() + (86400 * 30), '/');
```

Comment: Was like that before I added a specific domain...was hoping that will solve the problem. But doesn't.

Comment: you have no problem if generate cookie in "domain.tld" site but if generate cookie from another site by this domain u can't access

Comment: It doesn't seem to set the cookie either way. With a specified domain or just a /.